# how to left join two tables in a single row (oracle 11g or standard sql)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Assume primary keys are in the form p*n* for parents and c*n* for children where n is a positive integer.

```
Parent (id primary key)                                       -- may not have children
Child  (id primary key, parent_id references Parent not null) -- children must have a parent

select Parent.id pid, Children.id cid 
from Parent 
left join Child on Parent.id = Child.parent_id
```

Results: (p1 has two children and p2 has none)

```
p1, c1
p1, c2
p2, null
```

What i want is:

```
p1,   c1,   c2
p2, null, null
```

Is there a standarized way to do this? (like some sort of join or reserved keyword)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use listagg for this.  It returns the children in one column.

```
select Parent.id pid, listagg(Children.id, ', ') within group (order by     Children.id) the_children
from Parent 
     left join Child on Parent.id = Child.parent_id
group by Parent.id
```